# removing invalid characters from (json) string

Tags: go

I'm am executing a command in a go program which gives me some output with the structure

```
  c := exec.Command("mycommand")
  stdout, _ := c.Output()
```

Output

```
{
 'name': 'mike',
 'phone': '12345'
},
{
 'name': 'jim',
 'phone': '1234'
}, //notice the final comma
```

To make valid json, I am trying to prepend `[` and then append `]`, and, finally, remove the final comma.

```
k := "["
mystring := string(stdout)
k += mystring
k += "]"
str := strings.Replace(k, "},]", "}]", -1)

w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
fmt.Fprintf(w, str)
```

When I put the final product in a json validator, I get this error

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
[{  
---^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'
```

Question: is there a way to do json.Compact or something similar on a string, or how can I make valid json in this situation?

Update

this is the output that my coding magic produces. I'm not sure exactly what part of it is `invalid`

```
[{
  'name': 'Leroy',
  'phone': '12345'
},
{
  'name': 'Jimmy',
  'phone': '23456'
}]
```

Comment: Can you update with your final json?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I updated OP with final output. Thanks for looking

Comment: Single quotes aren't valid json either. Can you fix what is generating this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JimB pointed out in comments single quotes are not valid json. So if you run another string replace `` k = strings.Replace(k, `'`, `"`, -1) `` to produce this;

```
[{
    "name": "Leroy",
    "phone": "12345"
}, {
    "name": "Jimmy",
    "phone": "23456"
}]
```

Then it should work as you expect.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work as soon as you encounter escaped quotes.